# Is it safe to permit using sudo to application-created users?

Tags: permissions, sudo, security, jenkins

I have a jenkins setup on my server that has automatically created the `jenkins` user, which is used for its os-operations. However, I need Jenkins to stop and start a service (via `systemctl`) after a specific build has been completed.

My current script (that gets executed after a build of `myapp`) looks like this:

```
sudo systemctl stop myapp
rm -f /opt/myapp/myapp.jar
mv target/myapp.jar /opt/myapp
sudo systemctl start myapp
```

To make this work, I simply added the `jenkins` user to the sudoers file for all commands without password prompt:

```
jenkins ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Is it safe to do this? What vulnerabilities do I expose myself to? Is there a better way to do this? If yes, how?

Comment: I haven't tried, but did you consider using logrotate "on demand"?